# The given key was not present in the dictionary - Visual studio SSDT Deploy

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SSDT project in Visual Studio 2017 and multiple reports working off a shared data source. I can build all the reports and also preview them with the ability to refresh the data. However when I click deploy I receive the error message

Error  : The given key was not present in the dictionary.

I have checked the project deployment details e.g (target sever details, Target Report Folder etc.) and they are all correct. Could anyone advise the best way to debug this error? 
[Visual Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIguR.png)
[Deployment Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsJ6T.png)

Comment: Could you attach a picture of the details you filled out and the error message ?

Comment: I have added links in the question.

Comment: I crosschecked yours to mine and it seems fine
[Have a look at this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/64d8055c-303f-47f9-a5b1-015642647426/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: Thanks however as below I am not having any issues with previewing reports or refreshing the data source. I am getting the error when I deploy to the report server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem using Microsoft Reporting Services 1.17 installed from Extensions and Updates in VS2017 15.3.5. I debugged with Visual Studio and decompiled with [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) which pointed to an error in Microsoft.ReportingServices.BuildProcess.dll. Connection properties were being looked up by URL in a dictionary. As far as I can see, this dictionary never gets populated.
The solution was to uninstall the extension and install [SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.0 preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's feedback.  I found the bug and will release a fix with the next version of the Reporting Services VSIX.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Is it possible to download some sort of Beta version of the VSIX with this fix somewhere?

Comment: Hello Daan - once I get a release build for this, I'll work with management to get the Reporting Services VSIX updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an .rdl.data file in the report project directory next to your .rdl file.  If you close Report Designer, delete that file, and try and preview again, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks however it is not the preview that I am having an issue with that works fine. The error happens when I deploy the report.

Answer (score 0):

I came across with the same issue. The problem was that  I had no issues when I deploy my report and I tried to access it through URL, but when I tried to access programmatically the browser launch this error 'The given key was not present in the dictionary'.I investigated and found that I was not set up the visibility flag as 'false' on the code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportparameter.aspx

ReportParameter(String, String, Boolean)
Instantiates a new ReportParameter with a name, a value, and a visibility flag.

Finally, my code was something sort of this:

```
            this.rptViewer.Reset();

            rptViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
            MyReportServerCredentials credencial = new MyReportServerCredentials();
            rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = credencial;

            this.rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(this.ReportServerUrl);
            this.rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = ReportUrl;

            this.rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(this.ReportServerUrl);
            this.rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = ReportUrl;

            ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("param1", new string[] { null }, false);
            ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("param2", new string[] { null }, false);
            ReportParameter p3 = new ReportParameter("param3", new string[] { null }, false);
            ReportParameter p4 = new ReportParameter("param4", new string[] { null }, false);


            this.rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1, p2, p3, p4 });

            this.rptViewer.AsyncRendering = false;
            this.rptViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
            this.rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

I hope it helps!